# Динамическое выделение памяти под поля структуры в СИ

Tags: c, структуры

Вот код, необходимо сделать так, чтобы в массивы `name` и `number` можно было записать строку неопределенной длины... Мне желательно увидеть уже готовый код, так мне легче разобраться. Спасибо.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    struct klass
    {
       char name[100];
       char number[100];
    };
    int main()
    {
    FILE *f;
    struct klass p;
    gets(p.name);
    gets(p.number);
    f = fopen("3.txt","w");
    fputs(p.name, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Откройте `<string>` из C++, там готовый код. Или вам чтобы скопипастить?

Comment: Вот список библиотек, поддерживающих «высокоуровневые» динамические строки в C, со сравнением: http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison

Comment: @VladD Сейчас мне лучше бы просто скопипастить!)

Comment: Ну так выберите из списка любую с подходящей вам лицензией. Будьте готовы к тому, что код сложный. А вообще, за готовыми решениями, это не сюда.

Comment: @VladD к такому меня еще не готовили. Очень хочется сделать универсальную программку, а времени совсем нет. Может есть другое решение или оно действительно очень сложное?

Comment: @LaKO: Есть много решений, некоторые из них в списке :-) Все довольно сложные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[[[@LaKO](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako), Вас пугают. На самом деле все просто

```
// dynstr.c примитивная динамическая строка однобайтных символов
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DYNAINCR(cur) ((cur) ? ((cur) / 4 + 2) : 16)

static inline char *
strpush_back (char *str, int *capacity, int *curlen, const char c)
{
  if (*curlen + 2 >  *capacity) // +2 т.к. кроме char c добавляем в конец еще и 0 
    if (!(str = (char *)realloc(str, (*capacity) += DYNAINCR(*curlen))))
      return 0;
  str[(*curlen)++] = c;
  str[*curlen] = 0;  // это не обязательно, иногда нежелательно
  return str;
}

main ()
{
  char *s = 0;
  int size = 0, oldsize = 0, len = 0, i;

  for (i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++) {

    char  *t = s;
    s = strpush_back(s, &size, &len, i);
    if (t != s) {
      puts("string created or moved");
      if (!s) {
        puts("Ooops! No memory... Exit");
        exit (-1);
      }
    }

    if (size != oldsize) {
      oldsize = size;
      printf ("size: %d len: %d s: [%s]\n",
          size, len, s);
    }

  }

  return puts(s) == EOF;
}
```

Как видите, код добавляющий байт к строке занимает всего десяток строк. Думаю сами разберетесь.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc dynstr.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
string created or moved
size: 16 len: 1 s: [A]
size: 21 len: 16 s: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP]
size: 28 len: 21 s: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU]
size: 36 len: 28 s: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]
size: 46 len: 36 s: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcd]
size: 59 len: 46 s: [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmn]
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

g++ тоже компилирует.

Очевидно, что можно изменить интерфейс, описывая строку тем или иным дескриптором, получая (не проверял)

```
struct string {
  char *data;
  int capacity, curlen;
};
char *str_push_back (struct string *ps, int c); // return ps->data;
```

или

```
struct dstr {
    int capacity, curlen;
};
char *strd_push_back (char *str, struct dstr *pd, int c); // return str;
```

На самом деле, наиболее интересным здесь является написание эффективной DYNAINCR(). Видимо, этот макрос (функция) должен сначала несколько раз выделять по 16 (или что-то в таком духе) байт, потом некую функцию от текущей длины, а затем (скажем, при размере от страницы памяти) по одной странице.

Скорее всего, тут трудно придумать нечто универсально эффективное, поэтому можно переопределять DYNAINCR в своей программе.

```
#ifdef DYNAINCR
#undef DYNAINCR
#define DYNAINCR(x) ...
#else
#define DYNAINCR(x) ...
#endif
```

В общем, [[[[@LaKO](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako)](/users/6442/lako), экспериментируйте, а главное сами побольше пишите.

Answer (score 1):

Для ввода строк неизвестной длинны в Си можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
while((ch=getchar())!='\n') {
   ... обработка символа char ch ...
}
```

Цикл работает пока функция [getchar()](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/13/getchar.htm) вычитывает символ из стандартного потока stdin неравный "переносу строки" в тело цикла можно вставить обработку полученного символа например вызов функции strpush_back, предложенной [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp).

Вот вариант решения вашей задачи:
(проверено gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#define DYNAINCR(cur) ((cur) ? ((cur) / 4 + 2) : 16)

static inline char *
strpush_back (char *str, int *capacity, int *curlen, const char c)
{
  if (*curlen + 2 >  *capacity) // +2 т.к. кроме char c добавляем в конец еще и 0 
    if (!(str = (char *)realloc(str, (*capacity) += DYNAINCR(*curlen))))
      return 0;
  str[(*curlen)++] = c;
  str[*curlen] = 0;  // это не обязательно, иногда нежелательно
  return str;
}


char *read_string(){

    char *s = 0;
    char ch;
    int size = 0, len = 0;

    while((ch=getchar())!='\n') {   //13 -- ASCII for CR

        char  *t = s;

        s = strpush_back(s, &size, &len, ch);

        if (t != s) {
              //puts("string created or moved");
              if (!s) {
                puts("Ooops! No memory... Exit");
                exit (-1);
              }
        }

    }

    return s;
}

struct klass
{
   char *name;
   char *number;
};

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *f;

    struct klass p;

    //gets(p.name);
    puts("Enter name:");
    p.name = read_string();
    //gets(p.number);
    puts("Enter number:");
    p.number = read_string();

    f = fopen("3.txt","w");
    fputs(p.name, f);
    fclose(f);


    free(p.name);
    p.name=NULL;
    free(p.number);
    p.number=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Или стандартную для Linux функцию `getline()`

Из `man 3 getline`:

       ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
       ssize_t getdelim(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim, FILE *stream);